# convert DF to dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a df and I want to convert it to a dict.

df looks like following.

```
Colleges     Location       Streams
JNTU         Hyd,Andhra      ECE,CSE,EE
OU           Hyd,Andhra      ECE,CSE,EE
```

I want the dict output like

```
{Colleges: JNTU , Location : Hyd,Andhra, Streams : ECE,CSE,EE}
```

Any inputs/ help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post code that creates the dataframe. And make the desired result real python. `ECE,CSE,EE` is a tuple holding values from 3 variables. I assume you really wanted a list of strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas ***to_dict*** method through you can convert *DataFrame* to *dict*

See the in-detail **[to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)**
like this

```
df.to_dict('records')
```

Output will be

```
[
{"Colleges": "JNTU" , "Location" : "Hyd,Andhra", "Streams" : "ECE,CSE,EE"},
{"Colleges": "OU" , "Location" : "Hyd,Andhra", "Streams" : "ECE,CSE,EE"},
]
```